# kibana : Coordinate Map: Could not retrieve manifest from the tile service: status -1

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, xpack

i'v use kibana5 to learn,when i read to this "[enter link description here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/tutorial-visualizing.html)" using a coordinate map chart to visualize geographic information,
the waring occur "Coordinate Map: Could not retrieve manifest from the tile service: status -1" 
how can i solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Simply the service is not reachable in your network. Use a proper proxy server or move from elastic map service to your local server.